# How to substitute values to equation in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

It's a fundamental use and WolframAlpha appeared entirely uncooperative.

Given:

```
E = (4.49*10^16 Joules),
m = (1 kilogram),
c = (speed of light in vacuum),
```

and the equation:

```
v = (sqrt(E) c sqrt(2 c^2 m+E))/(c^2 m+E)
```

Give me v for the values given. Just substitute the values and calculate the result.

But I'm getting all kind of weird results. Graphs. Roots of equation where m is the variable. Definition of vacuum. *"true"* (yes, W.A. confirms, c does equal speed of light in vacuum).

But to substitute all the values, get a simple number, the output in meters/second? That's apparently too much to ask for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @pnuts: How would you rewrite the equation to make it right for WA?

Comment: @pnuts: The one for `v`. Or did you mean a different one in your comment?